# Why is potential energy positive in simple harmonic motion?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, potential-energy, conventions, oscillators

My textbook claims;

> "Potential energy is positive by choice of undermined constant in potential energy"

$$
 PE=\frac{1}{2} A^2 \sin^2 (\omega t+\phi).
$$

What does the statement mean? Which constants are they referring to?

Comment: undermined $\to$ undetermined/indetermined ?

Comment: Let $V$ be the potential energy of the simple harmonic oscillator. You can add a constant $V_0$ to $V$ so that the new potential is $V'=V+V_0$. Doing so does not change motion of the simple harmonic oscillator. This means that if the potential energy is negative you can simply add a sufficiently large positive constant to make the potential positive.

Comment: The potential energy is $\frac{1}{2} kx^2$, which is positive definite.

Comment: It's probably a printing mistake  in my textbook, apart from that both explanations seem reasonable thanks :). But why doesn't the potential energy change on adding a constant?

Comment: Which textbook?

Comment: class 11 cbse, ncert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from ZeroTheHero's comment, potential energy at point $A$ is calculated as an integral of the form:
$$
-\int_O^A{Fdx}=-\int_O^A{(-kx)dx}=\frac{1}{2}kA^2+C
$$
Reference point $O$ is free to choose and therefore $C$ is an arbitrary constant and may be negative.

This brings us back to the textbook which probably meant to say that "PE is positive by choice of the **underlying** constant $C$". We normally select O at $x=0$ so $C=0$.